# Unable to cover page messages code from test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, pagemessages

The controller is working as expected even try block is covering except the success message even warning messages are also covering. But i didn't set up any exception in my test class.

Following code is not covered in my test class
[image]

Controller:

```
public with sharing class RelatedRecords {
public List<wrapLead> wrapLeadList {get; set;}
public List<wrapLeadSecond> selectedLeads{get;set;}
public boolean verify{get;set;}
public boolean timer {get; set;}
public RelatedRecords(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl)
{
wrapLeadList = new List<wrapLead>();
selectedLeads = new List<wrapLeadSecond>();
RelatedList();
}
public void RelatedList()
{
    String conId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    Lead Related=[Select id,UniqueKey__c from lead where id=:conId];
    if(Related.UniqueKey__c != null)
    {
        For(Lead Lcc:[SELECT id,Name,Company,UniqueKey__c,City,state,Email,Phone,Owner.name,Status,LastActivityDate,IsContact__c,Flag_Type__c FROM lead WHERE ID !=:conId AND UniqueKey__c=:Related.UniqueKey__c])
        {
            If(lcc.IsContact__c == false)
            {
                wrapLeadList.add(new wrapLead(Lcc));                   
            }
            if(lcc.IsContact__c == True)
            {
                selectedLeads.add(new wrapLeadSecond(Lcc));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //wrapLeadList = null;
        selectedLeads = null;
        verify=false;
    }
}
public void updateLeads()
{
    System.debug('Accounts account loop');
    Lead[] UpdateLeads = New Lead[]{};
    If(wrapLeadList <> null && !wrapLeadList.isEmpty())
    {
        for(wrapLead w : wrapLeadList)
        {
            Lead a = new Lead();
            a.id=w.lcc.id;
            System.debug('For Loop************'+w.lcc.id);
            a.IsContact__c =false;
            UpdateLeads.add(a);
         }
     }
     If(selectedLeads <> null && !selectedLeads.isEmpty())
     {
         for(wrapLeadSecond w : selectedLeads)
         {
             If( String.isBlank(w.lcc.Flag_Type__c) || !w.lcc.Flag_Type__c.equals('Master') )
             {
                 Lead a = new Lead();
                 a.id=w.lcc.id;
                 System.debug('For Loop************'+w.lcc.id);
                 a.IsContact__c =true;
                 UpdateLeads.add(a);
             }
         }
      }
     try 
     {
        If(UpdateLeads <> null && !UpdateLeads.isEmpty())
        {
            update UpdateLeads;
            //PageUtility.showConfirm('Confirm');
        }
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(
        ApexPages.SEVERITY.Confirm,
        'Records are successfully updated'));
        timerOn();
     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(
                        ApexPages.SEVERITY.Fatal,ex.getMessage()));
     }
     //ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Records have been saved successfully',''));
     //PageUtility.showConfirm('Confirm Message');
}
public void clearMessage(){
        ApexPages.getMessages().clear();

    }
    public void timerOn(){
        timer = true;
    }

    public void timerOff(){
        timer = false;
    }
public void processSelected()
{
    for(Integer i = wrapLeadList.size() - 1;i >= 0;--i)
    {
        wrapLead wrapLeads= wrapLeadList[i];
        If (wrapLeads.selected== True)
        {
            selectedLeads.add(New  wrapLeadSecond(wrapLeads.lcc));
            wrapLeadList.remove(i);
        }
    }   
}
public void processUnselected() 
{
    String removeIdfor=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('IdParam');
    system.debug('@@@ --> '+ removeIdfor);
    for(Integer i = selectedLeads.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        if(selectedLeads[i].lcc.Id.equals(removeIdfor))
        {
            wrapLeadList.add(New wrapLead(selectedLeads[i].lcc));
            //wrapLeadList[i].selected=false;
            selectedLeads.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
public class wrapLead 
{
    public Lead lcc {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    //This is the contructor method. When we create a new wrapAccount object we pass a Account that is set to the acc property. We also set the selected value to false
    public wrapLead(Lead l) 
    {    
        lcc = l;
        selected = false;
    }
}
public class wrapLeadSecond
{
    public Lead lcc {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    //public String FullName{get;set;}
    public wrapLeadSecond(Lead a) 
    {
       lcc = a;
       //FullName=FullNames;
       selected = false;
    }   
}
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TestRelatedRecords {
public static testMethod void testwithRecords() 
    {
    List<Lead> allleads = new List<Lead>();
    For(integer i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
            allleads.add(new Lead(lastName='TestCavalry'+i,RecordTypeId ='0126F0000016MZP',
                                  Company ='Azuga Cavalry'+i,Status='New',Account_Category_new__c='Prospect',
                                  Account_Category__c='Regular',Lead_Category__c='Sales',Lead_Type__c='Association List',
                                 Lead_Source__c='NEFBA',LGS_Owner_new__c='Cavalry Test',SIC_Code_1__c='123',State='FL',Country='United States',
                             UniqueKey__c='1234'));
    }
        insert allleads;
        //System.debug('****Data'+leads.size());
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = Page.RelatedRecords;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc= new ApexPages.StandardController(allleads[0]);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',allleads[0].id);
        RelatedRecords controller= new RelatedRecords(sc);
        controller.RelatedList();
        System.debug('Data in related Records'+controller.wrapLeadList);
        //RelatedRecords.wrapLead wrapLeads= new RelatedRecords.wrapLead(allleads[0]);
        //wrapLeads.lcc=allleads[0];
        //wrapleads.selected=true;
        //RelatedRecords.wrapLead wrapLeadsInsert= new RelatedRecords.wrapLead(allleads[1]);
        //wrapLeadsInsert.selected=true;
        //controller.wrapLeadList=wrapLeadsInsert;
        List<RelatedRecords.wrapLead> wrapLeadLists = new List<RelatedRecords.wrapLead>();
        For(RelatedRecords.wrapLead item:controller.wrapLeadList)
        {
        RelatedRecords.wrapLead TempItem=item;
        TempItem.selected=true;
        wrapLeadLists.add(TempItem);
        }
        controller.wrapLeadList= wrapLeadLists;
        System.debug('Wrap final list********'+wrapLeadLists);
        //list<RelatedRecords.wrapLead> wrapLeadList= new list<RelatedRecords.wrapLead>();
        controller.processSelected();
        controller.updateLeads();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    public static testMethod void testwithRecordsBlank() 
    {
    List<Lead> allleads = new List<Lead>();
    For(integer i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
            allleads.add(new Lead(lastName='TestCavalry'+i,RecordTypeId ='0126F0000016MZP',
                                  Company ='Azuga Cavalry',Status='New',Account_Category_new__c='Prospect',
                                  Account_Category__c='Regular',Lead_Category__c='Sales',Lead_Type__c='Association List',
                                 Lead_Source__c='NEFBA',LGS_Owner_new__c='Cavalry Test',SIC_Code_1__c='123',State='FL',Country='United States',
                             UniqueKey__c='2345',IsContact__c =True));
     }                        
        insert allleads;
        //System.debug('****Data'+leads.size());
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pageRef = Page.RelatedRecords;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc= new ApexPages.StandardController(allleads[0]);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',allleads[0].id);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('IdParam',allleads[1].id);
        RelatedRecords controller= new RelatedRecords(sc);
        controller.RelatedList();
        List<RelatedRecords.wrapLeadSecond> selectedLeadslist = new List<RelatedRecords.wrapLeadSecond>();
        For(RelatedRecords.wrapLeadSecond item:controller.selectedLeads)
        {
        RelatedRecords.wrapLeadSecond TempItem=item;
        TempItem.selected=true;
        selectedLeadslist.add(TempItem);
        }
        controller.selectedLeads= selectedLeadslist;
        controller.processUnselected();
        controller.updateLeads();
        controller.timerOn();
        controller.timerOff();
        controller.clearMessage();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your DML is always throwing an exception. What do the logs tell you it is?

Comment: yes @DavidReed i have checked the duplicate records are adding to the wrapper class how to handle to prevent duplicates to add. And i have a question here I'm making dml only once but why duplicates are adding to the list

Comment: Thanks, David i have fixed my code thank you for the quick response.